# What does double pointer mean in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I begin to learn an Objective-C after 5 years of experience in Java and don't understand some of it's constructions. What does this Some_Object** mean? For example in the method definition here:

```
- (NSString *)checkLastUpdate:(NSUInteger)loggedId   
 returnMsgs:(NSMutableArray **)returnMsgs
 {
       ....
if (returnMsgs) 
 {
*returnMsgs = NewMsgs;
}
     }
```

It is pointer to pointer or what? And what it is the reason of using this?

Comment: Yeah it's pointer-to-pointer and it's used to allow a method to modify data that it's not able to return.  It's horrible, but necessary with C (Objective-C) as it lacks the references of C++ and Java.

Comment: Because it's error prone and ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's **[Pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29)-to-pointer** type, the same thing in C language.

I don't think it is a good behavior except for **error callback**.
For example, we call one function and need error info in case that the function failed:

```
- (id)handleData:(NSData *)inData error:(NSError **)outError;
{
if (inData == NULL || [inData length] == 0)
    {
    if (outError)
        *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:kDataErrorDomain code:-1 userInfo:NULL];
```

We can call like this :

```
NSError *error = NULL;
[self handleData:data error:&error];

if (error) {
    // Handle error
```

Comment: How will `if (outError)` ever be true ?

Comment: I think: if (*error) {
    // Handle error

Answer (score 2):

NSMutableArray ** means its a container that can hold address of the reference containing NSMutableArray e.g.

```
NSMutableArray * obj1; //obj1 can store reference of a mutable array
NSMutableArray ** obj2; // can contain address of obj1 that can store reference of a mutable array
```

You can use it in different scenarios most importantly

- If you want to return multiple objects from a function (Can be an error object or something else)

Answer (score 0):

Here the function is taking double pointer NSMutableArray as an output parameter and expect NSMutableArray instance will be initialize to nil

I think following is the use case to make use of double pointer over here,

```
-(void)functionName{  
NSMutableArray *pArray = nil;  

NSString *update = [self checkLastUpdate:[self getLoggId] returnMsgs:&pArray ];

}
```

Comment: A more classic example is the use of the `NSError` object returned by many API methods.